# Execute after subcomponents loaded in angular2?

Tags: angular

I have a home template with multiple "components".

In my HomeTemplate... I have:

```
<div>
<griditem1></griditem2>
<griditem2></griditem2>
</div>
```

How do I make it such that within the HomeTemplate typescript file, I execute a function AFTER griditem1 and griditem2 have been resolved? Meaning that they are converted into the HTML that represents the component.

Comment: Could you expand on the context - what's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [EventEmitter](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/EventEmitter-class.html).

On your `griditem1` and `griditem2`, you can have an `ngOnInit` that notifies through event emissions the `HomeComponent` you are trying to reach.

See [Learn Angular2](http://learnangular2.com/outputs/).

You will end up having something like this:

`<griditem1 (updated)="handleUpdate($event)"></gridItem1>`

```
@Output() updated = new EventEmitter();

ngOnInit() {
  // On finish loading notify parent.
  this.updated.emit();
}
```